# Catch set attribute event in SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an SVG document which contains a text element. The text is invisible and becomes visible via

```
<set attribute.../>
```

if I click on another SVG element (circle called "play").

```
<svg>
 ...

<circle  id="play" onclick="document.documentElement.unpauseAnimations()" ... />

<text id="ergsum0" fill="#000000" visibility="hidden" x="10" y="385"      font-size="22">Ergebnis = <tspan fill="#FF0000" font-size="22">1</tspan>
<set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden"  to="visible" begin="play.click"  />

 ...
 </svg>
```

Is it possible to catch the set attribute event via Java/ECMA Script? I.e. if the text is set to visible some event is fired and triggers the call of another (JavaScript) function?

I could set the attribute via JavaScript like

var target = document.querySelector('#ergsum0');
target.setAttribute('visibility','true');

and could catch this with a MutationObserver but I want to know if a change via 
     set attribute...

also triggers some change event which can be catched.

Thanks in advance

Comment: But why not using `addEventListener` directly, without the use of the `<set>` element?

Answer (score 0):

The `<set>` animation should send a SMIL [endEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#DOMSupport) when it finishes. You could do something like this...

```
<set attributeName="x" to="0" begin="0s" dur="0.5s" id="a"/>
<set attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS"
  to="green"
  begin="a.endEvent" dur="4s"/>
```

Or just add an eventListener in javascript to catch the event.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But what is the name of the event? target.addEventListener ('???', 
      function() { /* do something when changed*/}, 
      false);